# Is There any Alternatives to DTO in Spring Boot 2.0

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a backend api and a frontend client (Angular App) consuming this api, I have to redefine many DTOs  form Database Entities (almost 100). I wonder if there is an alternative to transform my entities with much more easier way than using Transformers.

Comment: No, there is no magic in spring boot. I can suggest you to use MapStruct or you can write your own transformers - BeanUtils definetly help you with that. Or you can use ResultTransformer check this article https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: In fact I tend to return an new Object in myRestController with only fields that I want to send based on the original Entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jackson API to convert the Entity object into DTO or any POJO class objects. Please check below URL for the code example.
https://www.thetechnojournals.com/2019/10/entity-object-conversion-to-dto-object.html

Comment: in fact I'm using ObjectMapper (2.3.5), but I can't get mapper.convert method working, any thoughts ?

Comment: Can you please share the code where you doing the conversion? It will be helpful if you can show the imports also in that class.

Comment: I just tried with version 2.3.5 and it started complaining missing classes at runtime. It will be better if you move to higher version of jackson, like 2.9.x.

Comment: knowing that I'm using Spring Boot 2.1.6, is there any version mismatch?

Comment: I am using spring boot 2.1.9 and jackson-databind 2.9.9. Also tried with Spring boot 2.1.6 and same jackson 2.9.9. In both cases it working fine. Are you explicitly declaring the jackson 2.3.5 dependency or it is coming because of some other dependency. In that case you can exclude that version and add jackson 2.9.9 dependency. Hopefully it should work then.  Also please can you check if you are using "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper".